# Counting String Length (strlen) on Array, Return Indexes Less than Max Characters

Tags: php, string

There must be an easier/automatic way to do this? I need to keep the `^^` delimiter and under 200 characters.

```
<?php

$string = 'Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.^^Kuaxalaxankoow te dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi whelsopewol te yeep ockino.^^Tep eb zo rino axail birtols wirr losurt din fottol buor obbicioncupp.^^Kivo yeep mohicro pit fottol evolaxarr dolbelmaxanco axas worr axas up axawosemo axagglossivo seuctick ockino.^^Oaxasupp te dinchaxarr!';
$stringlen = strlen($string);
echo $stringlen;

if ($stringlen > 200) {
$explode = explode('^^', $string);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($explode);
    echo '</pre>';
        $zero = strlen($explode[0]);
    echo $zero . '<br />';
    $one = strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]);
    echo $one . '<br />';
        $two = strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]);
    echo $two . '<br />';
        $three = strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]) + strlen($explode[3]);
    echo $three . '<br />';
        $four = strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]) + strlen($explode[3]) + strlen($explode[4]);
    echo $four . '<br /><br />';
    foreach ($explode as $x) {
        echo strlen($x) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
349
Array
(
    [0] => Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.
    [1] => Kuaxalaxankoow te dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi whelsopewol te yeep ockino.
    [2] => Tep eb zo rino axail birtols wirr losurt din fottol buor obbicioncupp.
    [3] => Kivo yeep mohicro pit fottol evolaxarr dolbelmaxanco axas worr axas up axawosemo axagglossivo seuctick ockino.
    [4] => Oaxasupp te dinchaxarr!
)

29 // [0] length
138 // [0] + [1] length
208 // [0]  + [1] + [2] length
318 // [0]  + [1] + [2] + [3] length
341 // [0]  + [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] length

29 // [0] length
109 // [1] length
70 // [2] length
110 // [3] length
23 // [4] length
```

I obviously have no idea how to dynamically do this.. here is one solution, but it doesn't account for the `count` of the array and how many possible additions.

```
if ($stringlen > 200) {
$explode = explode('^^', $string);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($explode);
    echo '</pre>';

        if (strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]) + strlen($explode[3]) + strlen($explode[4]) < 192) {
            echo 'five - [0]+[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]' . '<br />::';
            $goodlength = $explode[0] . '^^' . $explode[1] . '^^' . $explode[2] . '^^' . $explode[3] . '^^' . $explode[4];
            }
        elseif (strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]) + strlen($explode[3]) < 194) {
            echo 'four - [0]+[1]+[2]+[3]' . '<br />::';
            $goodlength = $explode[0] . '^^' . $explode[1] . '^^' . $explode[2] . '^^' . $explode[3];
        }
        elseif (strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) + strlen($explode[2]) < 196) {
            echo 'three - [0]+[1]+[2]' . '<br />::';
            $goodlength = $explode[0] . '^^' . $explode[1] . '^^' . $explode[2];
        }
        elseif (strlen($explode[0]) + strlen($explode[1]) < 198) {
            echo 'two - [0]+[1]' . '<br />::';
            $goodlength = $explode[0] . '^^' . $explode[1];
        }
        elseif (strlen($explode[0]) < 200) {
            echo 'on - [0]' . '<br />::';
            $goodlength = $explode[0];
        }

echo '<br />' .  $goodlength . '<br />';

}
```

This outputs:

> two - [0]+[1] :: Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.^^Kuaxalaxankoow te
>   dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi
>   whelsopewol te yeep ockino.

I've also tried with loops

```
$i = 0;
$length = '';
if ($stringlen > 200) {
$explode = explode('^^', $string);
    foreach ($explode as $x) {
        echo $i . '<br />';
        $length .= + strlen($x);
                    echo '<br />';
        if ($length > 200) {
            echo '<br />';
            break;
        }
                $i++;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> 0
>
> 1

But this still does not seem like a viable solution. Anyone with any good ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output with the given string please?

Comment: To count each array and if the next array is over 200 characters, exclude that index.  The output will have to include the delimiter which makes it more confusing. Anyways my expected output is quoted above... `Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.^^Kuaxalaxankoow te dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi whelsopewol te yeep ockino.` Which is a combination of `[0]` and `[1]` with the `^^` delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this dynamically:

Iterate the exploded sections of the string until adding the next section will push the length of the result over 200.

```
$len = 0;
foreach (explode('^^', $string) as $i => $section) {
    if (($len += strlen($section)) + $i * 2 > 200) break;
    $result[] = $section;
}
echo implode('^^', $result);
```

`+ $i * 2` accounts for the combined length of the delimiters in the result.

Comment: Short and sweet, all the right logic, works great :) Had to declare `$result = array();` before the loop but works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) to check to next position of the sequence `^^`, concatenate to the outputs string if the size is lesser than 200, and break the loop otherwise:

```
$string = 'Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.^^Kuaxalaxankoow te dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi whelsopewol te yeep ockino.^^Tep eb zo rino axail birtols wirr losurt din fottol buor obbicioncupp.^^Kivo yeep mohicro pit fottol evolaxarr dolbelmaxanco axas worr axas up axawosemo axagglossivo seuctick ockino.^^Oaxasupp te dinchaxarr!';

$out = '';
while (true) {
    // get the next position of ^^
    $pos = strpos($string, '^^');
    // if not found, or if the current output + next part > 200: break
    if ($pos === false || $pos + strlen($out) > 200) {
        // for the last part, remove the trailing ^^
        if ($pos !== false && $out != '') {
            $out = substr($out, 0, -2);
        }
        break ;
    }
    // append the current part to the output
    $out .= substr($string, 0, $pos + 2);
    // reduce the current string
    $string = substr($string, $pos + 2);
}
echo $out;
```

Outputs:

> Lousaxafro pi Lowaxaskaxafro.^^Kuaxalaxankoow te dincloaxaso yeep axaccorolaxatien fupp axaghtick velo telquo pi whelsopewol te yeep ockino.

Comment: What was the mistake here please? Thank you.

Comment: Looks legit to me.

Comment: Not sure what the mistake might be, but a quick `substr()` and `strrpos()` would be far less work than this looping and building up the result.

Comment: Thank you @salathe for the reply. Oh, yes, probably.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of that. It's a shortened version of "legitimate", as in "valid". The abbreviated version is also a slang term, meaning something like "cool", but I don't really talk that way, so I meant it more like the first way.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you @Don'tPanic for the explanation. That's what I though you said.

Answer (score 0):

you can count the length of the string and add every string length from the beginning of the array by nesting `foreach` and `for` loop.
example :

```
<?php
$string = ...;

$parts = explode('^^',$string);
$length = [];

foreach($parts as $index => $value) {
   $length[$index] = 0;
   for($i = 0;$i < $index; $i++) {
       $length[$index] += strlen($parts[$i]);
   }
}

print_r($parts);
print_r($length);
```